# How to create Java object from Firebase

Tags: android

I have a Firebase DB where I am trying to store 'Chat Sessions', in the code these are chat items which contain a date (the last msg sent) an ArrayList of 2 users and a list of messages. I save this to firebase fine and it creates a nice nested tree structure of it all. The issue I have is loading it all back in and trying to create a ChatItem object from the data that is a child of the key (eg lastMessage, messages and users).
All my code is below.
Thanks in Advance
[Tree Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVmpQ.png)
[Expanded Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xvy5.png)

Save obj to Firebase (works fine, just for ref)

```java
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        DatabaseReference reference;
                        currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);


                        String chatKey = currentUser.getId() + selectedUser.getId();
                        ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

                        Message message = new Message(currentUser, selectedUser, "Hi!");
                        messages.add(message);
                        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
                        users.add(currentUser);
                        users.add(selectedUser);
                        ChatItem ci = new ChatItem(users, messages);


                        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                        reference.child("Chats").child(chatKey).setValue(ci);
                    }
```

Getting from Firebase (Broken with error below)

```java
      mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Chats");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String s = ds.getKey();


            if (s.contains(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())) {






                ChatItem ci =  ds.getValue(ChatItem.class);


                ci = ds.getValue(ChatItem.class);
                if (ci != null) {


                    chatMap.put(s, ci);
                }
                chatItems.add(ci);
                chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

The error I receive is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.softwareproject, PID: 27803
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:233)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:176)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:47)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:580)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:550)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:420)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:212)
        at com.example.softwareproject.ChatFragment.showData(ChatFragment.java:134)
        at com.example.softwareproject.ChatFragment.access$000(ChatFragment.java:33)
        at com.example.softwareproject.ChatFragment$1.onDataChange(ChatFragment.java:78)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

UPDATE:
ChatItem Class:

```java
package com.example.softwareproject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class ChatItem implements java.io.Serializable {


private Date lastMessage = null;
private ArrayList<Message> messages = null;
private ArrayList<User> users = null;

    public ChatItem(ArrayList<User> users, Date lastMessage, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
       this.users = users;
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public ChatItem(ArrayList<User> users, ArrayList<Message> messages) {
        this.users = users;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.lastMessage = messages.get(messages.size()-1).getMessageTime();
    }

    public ChatItem() {}
    public Date getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }

    public void addMessage (Message message){
        this.messages.add(message);
    }


    public ArrayList<User> getUsers(){


        return this.users;


    }

    public ArrayList<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setUsers(ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public void setLastMessage(Date lastMessage) {
        this.lastMessage = lastMessage;
    }

    public void setMessages(ArrayList<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2: (Message Class)

```java
package com.example.softwareproject;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Message implements  java.io.Serializable{
    private User sender = null;
    private User recipient = null;
    private String content = null;
    private Date messageTime;
    private int messageID = 0;

    public Message() {}
    public Message(User sender, User recipient, String content) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.content = content;
        this.messageTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    }

    public Message(User sender, User recipient, String content, Date messageTime) {
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
        this.content = content;
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }

    public User getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public User getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    public int getMessageID() {
        return messageID;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public Date getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public void setSender(User sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public void setRecipient(User recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public void setMessageTime(Date messageTime) {
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
    }

    public void setMessageID(int messageID) {
        this.messageID = messageID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share ChatItem Class

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your messages node. In your ChatItem class the variable messages is a arraylist while in the database it's a HashMap. I think the problem is there. To give a complete answer, need to see your Message class

Comment: I will update it now

Comment: Sorry for taking time. Did you solved the problem? I tried your code and it was working without a problem.Did u manually add data to the database? Try to remove the the node(CFKVn..) under chats and run your code.